# how to change font style of my app on user demand

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

I am making an android app and there i want to add a option from where user can change the font face(font style) for my app.
I want an **change font style** button and when user click on it, they can see the list of some font styles and whatever font style they choose from that list then i want whole app text's get change according to that font style.
I want your help guys.
Can I have the whole procedure in an easy way.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can give font names in `ListView` or `RadioButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CustomFont extends Activity
{
ArrayList<String> fontsArrayList;
ListView font_list;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_fonts); // Layout containing a listView with id fontListView

    fontsArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    addDataToArrayList();

    font_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.fontListView);
    font_list.setAdapter(new FontListAdapter());
    font_list.setOnItemClickListener(FontSelected);
}

private void addDataToArrayList()
{
    fontsArrayList.add("Sans Serif");
    fontsArrayList.add("Droid Mono Space");
    fontsArrayList.add("Serif");
    fontsArrayList.add("Acid Structure");
            fontsArrayList.add("Ananda Neptouch");
//Other Fonts you wish to add
}

OnItemClickListener FontSelected=new OnItemClickListener()
{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) 
{
    Typeface typeFace = SetTextAppearance.getFont(getAssets(), fontsArrayList.get(position));

  // You can get the font name from arraylist
     /* String fontName = fontsArrayList.get(position); */

// You can use the typeface for changing the font where you wish like
    /* textView.setTypeface(typeFace); */

}
};


// Adapter for ListView
public class FontListAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return fontsArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View list=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
        list=inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null); // Another Layout to be inflated as row for ListView. I have added a single textView in the layout
    }
    else
        list=(View)convertView;
    TextView textView=(TextView)list.findViewById(R.id.FontNameText);
    textView.setText(fontsArrayList.get(position));
    Typeface typeFace = SetTextAppearance.getFont(getAssets(), fontsArrayList.get(position));
    textView.setTypeface(typeFace);
    return list;
}

}

}

public class SetTextAppearance 
{
static AssetManager asm;

public static Typeface getFont(AssetManager mgr ,String fontName)
{
    Typeface typeFace = null;
    if (fontName.equals("Sans Serif")) {
        typeFace = Typeface.SANS_SERIF;
    }
    if (fontName.equals("Droid Mono Space")) {
        typeFace = Typeface.MONOSPACE;
    }
    if (fontName.equals("Serif")) {
        typeFace = Typeface.SERIF;
    }
    if (fontName.equals("Acid Structure")) {
        typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr,"fonts/"+"acidstructure.ttf");
    }
    if (fontName.equals("Ananda Neptouch")) {
        typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr,"fonts/"+"ananda_neptouch.ttf");
    }
}
}
```

Make sure you have imported your fonts file (.ttf) in assets/fonts

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by this code :

```
   //Put font in asset/fonts folder

   String fontPath = "fonts/FONTNAME.TTF";

   // Loading Font Face
   Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);
    textview.setTypeface(typeface ); //setting font to particular view
```

Hope it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you for apply font to Current app

Visit http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/18/fun-with-fonts/

Answer (score 0):

I have done that as below,

First store some fonts with extensions `ttf` in your assets folder.

Then in your working activity get fonts from assets into variable.

Then set them in a ListView or spinner or anything you want in your application.

Create a Typeface object.

After that get the position of List item selected and set it to Typeface.

Now set this typeface to your text in application,

Answer (score 0):

first, to make a listView with all the font's applied you have to make an Adapter that in the `getView()` method return a TextView with the right

to apply the font to everyview that's what i did:

- Store the `.ttf` files you need in your `/assets` forlder
- Load them in memory like this:

  `Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "font.ttf");`
- Make an adapter that in the [getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method return a TextView with the font applied according to the position.
- onItemClick apply the right font to all the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) ( or everyview that supports [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) ) recursively

  ```
  public void setTypefaceRecursive( View view, Typeface typeface ) {
      if( typeface == null )
          return;

      if( view instanceof ViewGroup ) {
          //set the typeface to all the sub views
          ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)view;
          for( int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++ )
              setTypefaceRecursive( parent.getChildAt(i), typeface );
      } else if( view instanceof TextView ) {
          ((TextView) view).setTypeface(typeface);
      }
  }
  ```
- Store the [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) object somewhere globally and apply it to every view tree you'll inflate/instance.

On thing i didn't do is that you could use reflection to set the [Typeface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) to all the View that may have the [setTypeface(Typeface typface)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface%29) method.

```
    try {
        view.getClass().getMethod("setTypeface", Typeface.class ).invoke(view, typeface);
    }catch( NoSuchMethodException e ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for for custom font and extend it to TextView like this

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

@SuppressWarnings("null")
private void init() {
    if (!isInEditMode()) {

        String fontName = null;// get your fontName here 
        // default style
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                "helveticaneue_bold.ttf");

        /*
         * Check User Selected font style
         * */

        if (fontName.equals("Sans Serif")) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "sans_serif.ttf");
        }
        if (fontName.equals("Droid Mono Space")) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "droid_mono_space.ttf");
        }
        if (fontName.equals("Serif")) {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "serif.ttf");
        }

        setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

}

Now in your every xml instead of TextView use this class as below

```
  <yourpackagename.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            style="@style/buttontext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/company_profile" >
        </yourpackagename.CustomTextView>
```

Now on every event click for your style change, get instance of your selected font style in init() method and this will do. Also dont forget to put your font styles (.ttf) into assets folder.